# ruby-rubocop-revived not working as expect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, visual-studio-code, rubocop

I'm having error on my vscode while trying to use ruby-rubocop-revived plugin:

`Error on parsing output (It might non-JSON output) : "Inspecting 1 file\nC\n\nOffenses:\n\nd:\repo/ingressonanetpp/models:3:1: C: Style/Documentation: Missing top-level documentation comment for class Company.\nclass Company < ApplicationRecord\n^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n\n1 file inspected, 1 offense detected\n"`

The problem: the integration aren't marking the code, only throwing this "error", also when running rubocop on terminal, I don't get any offense

Cool things to know about: I'm using vscode on windows with a WLS2 where my ruby and rubocop gem are installed (with rbenv, rvm I got same error)
Vscode extensions installed:

- Better Haml
- change-case
- CircleCI
- Docker
- GitLens
- indent-rainbow
- Live Share
- Ruby (from Peng Lv)
- ruby-rubocop-revived (from LoranKloeze)
- VSCode Ruby
- WSL

Vscode settings.json

```
 {
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
        "PowerShell": {
            "source": "PowerShell",
            "icon": "terminal-powershell"
        },
        "Command Prompt": {
            "path": [
                "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
                "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
            ],
            "args": [],
            "icon": "terminal-cmd"
        },
        "Git Bash": {
            "source": "Git Bash"
        },
        "Ubuntu (WSL)": {
            "path": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\wsl.exe",
            "args": [
                "-d",
                "Ubuntu"
            ]
        }
    },
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Ubuntu (WSL)",
    "terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "'Meslo LG S for Powerline'",
    "ruby.rubocop.executePath": "D:/repo/",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "ruby.rubocop.onSave": true,
    "ruby.rubocop.suppressRubocopWarnings": true
}
```

For what I know the executePath is reaching my rubocop.bat on repo folder... this bat have this content:

```
@echo off
wsl ~/.rbenv/shims/rubocop $^(echo '%*' ^| sed -e 's^|\\^|/^|g' -e 's^|\^([A-Za-z]\^)\:/\^(.*\^)^|/mnt/\L\1\E/\2^|g'^)
```

.rubocop.yml

```
Layout/LineLength:
  Max: 150
  IgnoredPatterns: ['\A#']

Style/Documentation:
  Enabled: false

Lint/MissingSuper:
  Enabled: false

Metrics/ParameterLists:
  Max: 10

Metrics/MethodLength:
  Max: 20

AllCops:
  TargetRubyVersion: 3.2.1
  SuggestExtensions: false
  NewCops: disable
  Exclude:
    - 'bin/**/*'
    - 'Gemfile'
    - 'db/schema.rb'
    - 'db/migrate/*.rb'
    - 'config/**/*.rb'
    - 'spec/**/*_spec.rb'
    - 'spec/*_helper.rb'
    - '**/vendor/**/*'
```

Comment: Use [ruby-lsp](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Shopify.ruby-lsp) instead of the janky extensions you're using now. Uninstall: Ruby (from Peng Lv); ruby-rubocop-revived (from LoranKloeze); VSCode Ruby.

Comment: @anothermh how should I configure it with WSL2 setup?

Comment: Don't ask broadly how to configure it; configure it yourself, and if it doesn't work then ask how to resolve the specific error you receive.

Comment: @anothermh well, I asked because I already tried it... but didn't see any options path to set rbenv from wls or similar, or set the path of ruby... Error that I got here: 

Failed to activate rbenv environment: Command failed: undefined -ic 'rbenv exec ruby --disable-gems -rjson -e "printf(%{RUBY_ENV_ACTIVATE%sRUBY_ENV_ACTIVATE}, JSON.dump(ENV.to_h))"'
'undefined'

Comment: You're misunderstanding me. If you have trouble [configuring ruby-lsp](https://github.com/Shopify/vscode-ruby-lsp#ruby-version-managers) in WSL then you need to ask a new question because it is unrelated to the presently asked question, and the comments section is not the place to ask and receive an answer to an unrelated question.

Comment: I had it working with "extension setup" on my old mac (but for N reasons I don't have it anymore)... I just asked broadly how to configure it, because I thought that you have ideia (or even a link) on how to configure it with wsl2 (as I didn't find anything related or could make it works)